# Recdef and shelved goals

Tags: recursion, coq

I have made the following inductive data type and recursive functions.

```
Require Coq.Lists.List.

Inductive PairTree : Type :=
| PTLeaf : PairTree
| PTBranch : (nat*nat) -> PairTree -> PairTree -> PairTree.

Fixpoint smush (r m : list nat) : list nat :=
  match m with
    | nil => r
    | h :: t => smush (h :: r) t
  end.
```

I've defined the following function using these, with an auxiliary "gas" parameter so that Coq's termination rules are easily satisfied.

```
Fixpoint fueled_prefix_part (gas : nat) (r m : list nat) : PairTree :=
  match gas with
    | 0 => PTLeaf
    | S gas' =>
      match r with
        | nil => PTLeaf
        | f :: fs =>
          match fs with
            | nil => PTLeaf
            | f' :: fs' =>
              PTBranch (f, f')
                       (fueled_prefix_part gas' (smush fs' m) nil)
                       (fueled_prefix_part gas' (f :: fs') (f' :: m))
          end
      end
  end.
```

However, I wanted to extract actual code from this and run it. Thus, instead of structural recursion on gas, I could get nicer extracted code if instead I could use the following code, since then I could use some other nat-like data type with < (e.g. Haskell Integers).

```
Require Import Recdef.
Require Export Coq.omega.Omega.
Require Export Coq.Lists.List.

(* Insert definitions of PairTree and smush here. *)

Function fpp' (gas: nat) (r m: list nat) {measure (fun x => x) gas}: PairTree :=
  match 0 <? gas with
    | false => PTLeaf
    | true =>
      match r with
        | nil => PTLeaf
        | f :: fs =>
          match fs with
            | nil => PTLeaf
            | f' :: fs' =>
              let gas' := gas - 1 in
              PTBranch (f, f')
                       (fpp' gas' (smush fs' m) nil)
                       (fpp' gas' (f :: fs') (f' :: m))
          end
      end
  end.
```

Of course we can't end there; we have to prove that this terminates. The following would appear to prove the termination...

```
Proof.
  intro gas. destruct gas; intros _ _ teq _ _ _ _ _ _.
  inversion teq.
  omega.
  intro gas. destruct gas; intros _ _ teq _ _ _ _ _ _.
  inversion teq.
  omega.
```

At this point in *ProofGeneral* I see no goals in the goal screen, and in the response screen, I see the message

```
No more subgoals.
(dependent evars:)
```

So I type in

```
Defined.
```

and get the error message

```
Toplevel input, characters 0-8:
Error: Attempt to save a proof with shelved goals (in proof fpp'_terminate)
```

What on earth is going on? If I type

```
Unshelve.
Defined.
```

I get the same error.

Comment: After a bit of investigation, it is very likely that this is a Coq bug, could you report it at the Coq bugzilla?